# Correct syntax to get first name from POST react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, fetch

[image: POST]

Very new to coding.

How do i get around the item: in the POST ?

I have tried `item.firstname` and `item[firstname]`

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const url = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/1f0a9583-ce4d-4db1-85cb-3bab75576957";
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const result = await response.json();
  
  this.setState({
     firstname: result.firstname,
     middlename: result.middlename,
     surname: result.surname,
     city: result.city,
     postcode: result.postcode,
     state: result.state,
     about: result.about,
     formfirstname: result.firstname,
     formmiddlename: result.middlename,
     formsurname: result.surname,
     formcity: result.city,
     formpostcode: result.postcode,
     formstate: result.state,
     formabout: result.about
  });
}
```

Comment: `result` is an object with `Item` property. Value of `Item` property is another object with `firstname` and other properties. So to access `firstname`, you have to do --> `result.Item.firstname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with image suggest. **Item** is key of **result** object. So it would be this

```
 this.setState({
     firstname: result.Item.firstname,
     middlename: result.Item.middlename,
     surname: result.Item.surname,
     city: result.Item.city,
     postcode: result.Item.postcode,
     state: result.Item.state,
     about: result.Item.about,
     formfirstname: result.Item.firstname,
     formmiddlename: result.Item.middlename,
     formsurname: result.Item.surname,
     formcity: result.Item.city,
     formpostcode: result.Item.postcode,
     formstate: result.Item.state,
     formabout: result.Item.about
  })
```